# Appending and processing JS code that returned from the server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I got a backend API written in PHP (w/ Laravel) which has one specific controller that receives an ID, makes a few DB actions to retrieve some data and then populates a dynamic js code (simply attaching it as a string to a variable, and returns it) based on the DB results and returns this code as a string.
On the client side though, what I'm willing to achieve is that on each entrance to the website, an ajax call will be sent to this API endpoint and a dynamic js piece of code will be attached to the DOM (and will be executed as well, of course).
For now, the API works well and returns the exact code that I'm willing, and on the client side I'm able to fetch it via a simple xhr request and attach it to the DOM, but the only problem is that it doesn't execute.

Current JS code for the API call:

```
<script>
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/campaigns/1/1'; // get campaign

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

    function processRequest(e) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            let response = xhr.responseText;
            let div = document.getElementById('campaigns');
            div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', response );
        }
    }
</script>
```

And the response is a string that contains a whole new script to be attached (and executed).

Comment: How much do you implicitly trust the JS string that is being generated?  Would you give it the same level of trust as any other bit of JS your server returns (in your normal scripts etc), or could part of it be generated by a user (or worse, some _other_ user than the one it's rendered for)?

Comment: As far as I understand - you get the data but it just doesn't execute whenever you enter the page?

Comment: Why not just originally load the script to the page, and get the data the script uses via AJAX only?

Comment: @JamesThorpe It's only for internal use, and I simply haven't included all the security matters, since it's not part of the problem.

Comment: @Teemu Since I don't want to ask each of the clients to implement this script on their side, but make their life easier.

Comment: But you're just trying to add a script to the page?? You've the AJAX in a script, why not have a function which handles the passed data? Or have we all misunderstood your question?

Comment: @Teemu Just a matter of aesthetics. I don't want to make the client to embed this whole functionality by himself. But only a small piece of code which makes the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create script element dynamically every time you're receiving the code and append it in the body:

```
<script>
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/campaigns/1/1'; // get campaign
    var globalEval = eval;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

    function processRequest(e) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            let respondedJSCode = xhr.responseText;
            try {
                if(respondedJSCode){
                    let script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.text = respondedJSCode;
                    document.body.appendChild(script);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It still doesn't execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using dynamic script execution

```
const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/campaigns/1/1'; // get campaign

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

function processRequest(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        let response = xhr.responseText;

        // create a function with script

        let functionByDynamicScript= new Function(response);

        // execute the function
   functionByDynamicScript() } }
```

Comment: the `functionByDynamicScript()` will not be executed in global context.